# PHP Execute Ping Command

Tags: apache-2.2, php, bash

I have asked this question before but with not much success. I guess i was confused and did not put my question properly. So here it goes again.

Some points before i begin:

1. I am running FC 14
2. I did not install apache manually ... used yum
3. safe mode in PHP is turned OFF

Basically I want to execute ping command and show the results on the PHP page. The code I use is

```
<?php
$who = shell_exec('whoami');
$result1 = shell_exec("/webserver_commands/ping -c 4 www.google.com");
exec("ping -c 4 www.google.com",$result2);

echo $who;
echo "<br/>".$result1;
echo "<br/>".$result2;
?>
```

The Output I get is

```
apache 

Array
```

So I know the scripts are being run as the user 'apache'

In the apache log I see the following lines

```
sh: /webserver_commands/ping: Permission denied
ping: icmp open socket: Permission denied
```

I have made sure the directory /webserver_commands/ and the file ping in it are owned by the user apache of the group apache

```
917506 drwxrwxrwx.   2 apache apache  4096 Feb  4 18:29 webserver_commands
917507 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 43448 Feb  4 18:29 ping
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong here ?

thank you,
-ankit

Comment: Remove the write permissions for "other" - it's a security risk and is unnecessary. `chmod o-w ping`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apache` user does not have sufficient rights to send ICMP packets, consider using [Net_Ping](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Ping) library from PEAR instead.
If you are using Debian it can be installed using `apt-get install php-net-ping`

Comment: Unfortunately i need to execute multiple such commands including "free" and most of them are giving this error. will look into net_ping though. thanks !

Comment: You should disable SELinux in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and reboot then. Apparently the first `sh: /webserver_commands/ping: Permission denied` error is caused by SELinux, I don't see it on my Debian box.

Comment: while you are probably on the right track with selinux, disabling it entirely on a publicly accessible web server is a bad idea.

Comment: @patrick @alex You guys rule ! It was selinux after all. Disabled it temporarily and reloaded the page .. worked like a charm ! now just need to read up on what exactly selinux does and if i need it or not.

Comment: ping command executed by php might have insufficient permissions causing `ping: icmp open socket: Permission denied`. So, maybe SELinux must be Permissive and chmod can be used to tweak ping file permission http://phpipam.net/selinux-policy-for-icmp-checks/

Answer (score 2):

if you want to display $result2 you need to implode it. exec() puts its output into the second argument as an array.
So

> print(implode("<br>",$result2));

Or echo, whatever your preference

As for ping, its not working because it lost the setuid bit when you copied it. You need to do

```
chown root /webserver_commands/ping
chmod u+s /webserver_commands/ping
```

Comment: tried what you suggested. Get exactly the same error.

Comment: @ankit I didnt think of selinux (seeing another comment reminded me). The solution in the comment is to disable selinux completely, which is ill advised for a publicly accessible web server. I would see if someone else knows how to get selinux to allow /webserver_commands/ping to operate without disabling selinux completely.

Comment: In fact, I know how to alter a SELinux policy to allow these commands to operate, `audit2allow` and a number of other command line tools should be used as described [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/audit2allow) to create a binary policy alteration module and to install it.

Comment: @alex Thanks guys. I will look into the link and report back

Comment: @alex You guys rule ! It was selinux after all. Disabled it temporarily and reloaded the page .. worked like a charm ! now just need to read up on what exactly selinux does and if i need it or not.

Answer (score 0):

One potential cause is that `ping` is by design a root-only command so, in order to execute it from non-root users, many distributions have the setuid bit set on 'ping'; however, conversely, many do not - this may include FC14

If ping does not have the setuid bit set, and if you are willing to open up this *potential* (but unlikely) security hole you can `chmod u+s` on ping to allow it to be executed from any user.

Comment: No change. get the same error.I am however able to execute simple commands such as "cat"